# How make the row editable when edit button is clicked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

```
$('#dependents-info').on('click', '.btn-edit-dependent', function () {
                var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
                //what code will I put here?
            });
```

**I want to make the row editable when the Edit button is clicked, how can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create input fields inside the td then when you want to save them use javascript to load the values and store them. So you could do

```js
$('#dependents-info').on('click', '.btn-edit-dependent', function () {
                var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
               var newInput = currentTD.appendChild("input");
                newInput.setAttribute("id","newInput1");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `td` editable by adding `contenteditable="true"`. See below code.

```
        $('#dependents-info').on('click', '.btn-edit-dependent', function () {
            var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
            currentTD.prop("contenteditable","true");
        });
```

Hope this helps.